# Why onApply of unmodified CPropertyPage is called when other CPropertyPage is modified?

Tags: c++, winapi, visual-c++, mfc

I have 3 `CPropertyPage` pages in `CPropertySheet`. Whenever I modify the second one and press apply button onApply method from the first property page is also called.

Any proper way to handling it?

Comment: The Apply button is global to the property sheet and is supposed to commit changes made to all property pages. It is expected that all the property pages for which `SetModified(TRUE)` was called will have their `OnApply()` method invoked when the user clicks the Apply button. Just commit the relevant changes when that happens.

Comment: Could it be that SetModified(TRUE) somehow applies to all of the pages instead of one?

Comment: Nope,  that's a method of `CPropertyPage`, it only impacts the page it's called on. If `OnApply()` is invoked on your first page, then `SetModified(TRUE)` must have been called for that page someway.

Comment: Big thanks,  mate.